# How to decrypt Cisco Passwords type 7 using Python?

Tags: python, encryption, cisco

I'm trying to crack some cisco type 7 passwords, and so far, I did good realising the decryption algorithm described in the following exploit:
http://pen-testing.sans.org/resources/papers/gcih/cisco-ios-type-7-password-vulnerability-100566

```py
#Cisco password 7 constant is : "tfd;kfoA,.iyewrkldJKD", len = 21
CONSTANT = "tfd;kfoA,.iyewrkldJKD"
encoded_password = input('Enter a type-7 CISCO password: ').strip()
salt = int(encoded_password[:2], 16)
salt_ascii = ord(CONSTANT[salt - 1])
decoded = ''
i = 2
while i< len(encoded_password):
    encoded_char_int= int(encoded_password[i:i+2], 16)
    decoded+= '%c'%(salt_ascii ^ encoded_char_int)
    salt+=1
    if salt == 22:
        salt = 1
    salt_ascii = ord(CONSTANT[salt - 1])
    i+=2

print(decoded)
```

It is stated that passwords type 7 have a common salt constant that loop through which is :

```
CONSTANT = "tfd;kfoA,.iyewrkldJKD"
```

I successfully cracked passwords like: 0702385c4f1a0a1218000f5f527f
which is : mypassword365

However mypassword3651 could not get decrypted for a reason, that the password is long enough in a way that salt reaches the end of "tfd;kfoA,.iyewrkldJKD", and then I don't know what to do, do I have to loop through it again ?

I tried looping though again, but decryption is falty,

```
    if salt == 22:
        salt = 1
#mypasswordH
```

I tied getting to first position like the following :

```
salt = int(encoded_password[:2], 16)
first_pos = salt
.
.
.
.
    if salt == 22:
        salt = first_pos
```

None of the above trials were successful,

So my problem here is really with the decryption mechanism, in a simpler way, when the two first digits of the encrypted password are characters in the beggining of "tfd;kfoA,.iyewrkldJKD" eg t or f or d, there is no problem (the password is generally less than 21 chars and the program works), however if the 2 first digits are character are in the end of "tfd;kfoA,.iyewrkldJKD" like d or J or K or D, I run out of salts and the password gets decrypted partially, first half correct, and second false.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/theevilbit/ciscot7/blob/master/ciscot7.py) looks relevant...It's got a 51 long table and does rewind..

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment !!

Comment: Read the linked code and you'll understand.